# kendo-ui-core error build from sources

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

everybody! I try to build kendo-ui-core from source on Windows 7 server 64 bit, git and npm (last LTS version, from official site). I got eerors. Here is my log.

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'run',
    1 verbose cli   'build' ]
    2 info using npm@3.10.10
    3 info using node@v6.9.5
    4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
    5 info lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~prebuild: kendo-ui-core@1.0.0
    6 silly lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
    7 info lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~build: kendo-ui-core@1.0.0
    8 verbose lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    9 verbose lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~build: PATH: c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;d:\Distr\Development\Telerik\Telerik\kendo-ui-core\node_modules\.bin;c:\Users\x1\bin;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;c:\Windows\system32;c:\Windows;c:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin; D;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\Distr\Development\Java\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\cc\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;c:\Program Files\nodejs\;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Users\x1\AppData\Roaming\npm
    10 verbose lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~build: CWD: d:\Distr\Development\Telerik\Telerik\kendo-ui-core
    11 silly lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm install && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build' ]
    12 silly lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    13 info lifecycle kendo-ui-core@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
    14 verbose stack Error: kendo-ui-core@1.0.0 build: `npm install && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build`
    14 verbose stack Exit status 1
    14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
    14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
    14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
    15 verbose pkgid kendo-ui-core@1.0.0
    16 verbose cwd d:\Distr\Development\Telerik\Telerik\kendo-ui-core
    17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    18 error argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
    19 error node v6.9.5
    20 error npm  v3.10.10
    21 error code ELIFECYCLE
    22 error kendo-ui-core@1.0.0 build: `npm install && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the kendo-ui-core@1.0.0 build script 'npm install && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build'.
    23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the kendo-ui-core package,
    23 error not with npm itself.
    23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    23 error     npm install && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build
    23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    23 error     npm bugs kendo-ui-core
    23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    23 error     npm owner ls kendo-ui-core
    23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What's the problem? How to solve it? Thanks in advance.